# How can I make my code not change when an appStorage var changes

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an appStorage var "isLoggedIn". On the start of my app, I monitor this variable and redirect the user depending on its value. When "isLoggedIn" is false, The user can go create an account navigating with navigationLinks. On the account creation, I change "isLoggedIn" to true. The purpose of this change is so that when the user closes and opens the app, I can direct them to their home screen immediately. The only problem is, "isLoggedIn" is acting like a @Binding var and triggering code at the start of my app. Is there a way for me to only reread the value once the user opens the app again?

This is the code where I redirect my user according to the AppStorage Variables

```
struct DispatcherView: View {

@AppStorage("isLoggedIn") var isLoggedIn = false
@AppStorage("lastLoggedEmail") var lastLoggedEmail = ""
@AppStorage("lastLoggedUserType") var lastLoggedUserType = ""
@AppStorage("lastLoggedUserPassword") var lastLoggedUserPassword = ""

@State var isActive: Bool = false
@State var waitTime: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    
    VStack{
        
        if self.isActive{
            if isLoggedIn == false{

                StartUpView()
                    .onAppear(perform: {

                        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge]) { (_,_) in

                        }
                    })
            }
            else{

            if lastLoggedUserType == "Driver"{

                    DriverContentView(email: $lastLoggedEmail, userType: $lastLoggedUserType)
                        .onAppear(perform: {

                            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: lastLoggedEmail, password: lastLoggedUserPassword) { (res, err) in
                                if err != nil{print(err as Any)}
                            }

                            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge]) { (_,_) in

                            }
                        })

                }
                else if lastLoggedUserType == "Admin"{

                    AdminContentView(email: $lastLoggedEmail, userType: $lastLoggedUserType)
                        .onAppear(perform: {

                            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: lastLoggedEmail, password: lastLoggedUserPassword) { (res, err) in
                                if err != nil{print("ERROR signing user back in\(String(describing: err))")}
                            }

                            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge]) { (_,_) in

                            }
                        })

                }

            }
        }
        else{
            
            VStack{
                
                Spacer()
            Image("splashScreen")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .animation(waitTime == false ? .none : .spring())
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(Color.white)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
        }
    }
    .onAppear(){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2) {
            withAnimation{
                self.isActive = true
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
            waitTime = true
        }
    }
}
}
```

In the sign up view, once I have confirmed the users info, I make these changes.

```
                                        lastLoggedEmail = email
                                        lastLoggedUserPassword = password
                                        lastLoggedUserType = "Admin"
                                        isLoggedIn = true
```

Once these changes are made, I'm pretty confident that the app goes back to the DispatcherView and reruns the code according to the new changes. I came to this conclusion by putting dummy destinations in the navigationLink in the SignUpView. No matter what view I put in as a destination, it would briefly show that view and then pop to the dispatcher view where it responds to my changes.

I do not want the app to react to these changes immediately(In a similar fashion to @Binding and @State variables). I only want it to use them for the next time a user launches the app.

Comment: Read and write to `UserDefaults` directly without using `AppStorage`. There's probably a structural way to do it with `AppStorage` as well, but since you haven't included any code, it's all pretty speculative

Comment: Please make sure to read and learn how you can ask your question with a minimal example code, so we could see what you are actually facing instead of guessing game.

Comment: @jnpdx I have edited my question. I aplologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: If you don't want your app to "react" to them, as I suggested in my first comment, I would write them directly to `UserDefaults` rather than using the `AppStorage` wrappers.